# Restore (PITR) of CloudSQL (MySQL) fails with Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: mysql, restore, google-cloud-sql

When doing a PITR-Restore of a second generation Google CloudSQL instance, the restore fails with "Failed to Create" error. I cannot manipulate the instance clone, except reading logs and deleting it.

The mysql.err log shows messages like

```
E  2017-10-05T14:19:39.259084Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. 
E  Version: '5.7.14-google-log'  socket: '/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  (Google) 
E  2017-10-05T14:19:43.151623Z 3 [Warning] Timeout waiting for reply of binlog (file: mysql-bin.017364, pos: 601), semi-sync up to file , position 0. 
E  2017-10-05T14:19:43.151666Z 3 [Note] Semi-sync replication switched OFF. 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:46.173674Z 27 [Note] Aborted connection 27 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes) 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.364195Z 2 [Note] Aborted connection 2 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.395075Z 7 [Note] Aborted connection 7 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.668786Z 29 [Note] Aborted connection 29 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.668816Z 28 [Note] Aborted connection 28 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.875975Z 0 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:52.876143Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:54.876268Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:54.876451Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'root' 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:54.876479Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:54.876735Z 0 [Note] Binlog end 
E  2017-10-05T14:21:54.880101Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
```

My interpretation is that in Log file 17364 is some operation that exceeds `max_allowed_package`. (My intention is to restore to some point in log file 17454.) Given that this is technically a clone of a database instance that by definition had the same changes applied already, this error condition does not make too much sense to me.

How do I PITR then?

The procedure I've followed is [Performing a point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring#pitr), i.e. I've created a "clone" and chose "Clone from earlier position", then specified `mysql-bin.017364` as "Binary log file name".

**Edit: Setting `max_allowed_packet`**

After I've set the flag `max_allowed_packet` to 1073741824 (1 GiB; the max value) on the origin instance, the error message `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes` does not appear in the error logs anymore while cloning. However the CloudSQL-Instance still "failed to create", except now I have even less of an idea what to look for. The operations log says "an unknown error occured".

**Edit 2:**

The PITR operation fails not only with the above instance, but also with others. I have created an independent instance for testing and INSERT a few small rows now and then and try to PITR to various points in time.

To recap: independently of `max_allowed_packet`, independently of the size of actual write operations PITR fails with no expressive error message. The error message `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes` was a singular coincident.

Comment: Instead of using gcloud or the Console, can you export a copy of your instance locally using [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) then import that manual backup? By using MySQL commands directly, you can specify options for [row size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_binlog-row-event-max-size) to ensure you are within 'max_allowed_packet'. I know specifically with mysqldump you can set 'max_allowed_packer' and 'net_buffer_length' to stay within the limits.

Comment: That wouldn't help as I want to do PITR and I consider this a bug of CloudSQL.

Comment: To clarify, PITR is simply creating a backup of your instance from a specific position in the binary log, then restoring a clone instance with that backup. You can indeed achieve this via the MySQL commands as previously mentioned. As per the 'max_allowed_packet' issue, it is recommended to directly report this in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to notify Google.

Comment: I understand I can administrate the database with native tools. If I have to do that, because CloudSQL operations randomly fail and on top of that CloudSQL adds an opaque layer that hinders me to do proper debugging.... 

Why am I paying a markup for a managed service, then!?

Comment: To increase the 'max_allowed_packet' for your project and instance it is recommended to open an [Issue Report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as previously mentioned. The method of performing the backup manually is an interim workaround while the engineering team would ideally fix the actual issue for you. Of course you can always [directly deploy any number of other MySQL databases](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/browse?q=mysql) to the cloud which are not managed like Cloud SQL as you have correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

*- Posting the latest comment as the answer for completeness.*

To increase the '**max_allowed_packet**' for your project and instance it is recommended to open an [Issue Report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

An interim workaround while the engineering team fixes the actual issue for you is to use [MySQL PITR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) to save the point-in-time backup locally. You can then restore a clone instance with that manual backup.

By using MySQL commands directly, you can specify a lower option for row size to ensure you are within '**max_allowed_packet**'.

If you are just making a normal backup, you can also use the `mysqldump` command and lower the `max_allowed_packer` and `net_buffer_length` options to stay within the '**max_allowed_packet**' limit enforced when restoring the clone from the backup.

---

Of course you can always [directly deploy any number of other MySQL databases](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/browse?q=mysql) to the cloud which are not managed like Cloud SQL as you have correctly pointed out.